# Downloading a specific part of a file from a http server

Tags: ruby

How would I emulate the behavior of curl -r (range) in a ruby script without using backticks or other methods to run the curl binary?

I know how to start from the beginning of a file and save a file in chunks, but how would I start at a specific portion of the remote file then download for X bytes?

Say the file was 1000 bytes long, and I wanted to start at byte 60 and download 20 bytes from that point (finishing at 80). How would this be done?

Is there a gem wrapper around curl which is cross platform, or another gem that provides this support? Or is this possible with the standard open-uri or net::http libraries?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of asking a specific question about a problem you've encountered, you're asking how to do something without showing us what you've tried. There are many ways of generating HTTP requests but they all use different ways of specifying the needed headers, and without detailed information about what you're doing it is difficult to pinpoint an answer. You're also asking for recommendations for off-site resources. Please read "[ask]".

Comment: You might have misread most of the question or interpreted it poorly. The specific problem was how to replicate the headers curl sends. Also I was asking for libraries to provide this features or if the standard libraries provided these features. Plenty of other posts freely recommend gems as answers to specific problems. I did not specifically ask for third party resources or links. If you didn't know the answer there is no need to vote to close it.

Comment: That other questions recommend something is often cited as justification for repeating it, however they're often old questions prior to the rules being put into place, or the people not having responded as they are supposed to, often because they are not aware of the scope of Stack Overflow. It remains that asking for recommendations is off-topic, which is based on the community's agreement. See #4 in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with any library that lets you set request headers (all `curl -r` does is set the `Range` header), which should be pretty much any HTTP library. Net::HTTP, for its part, has a [`set_range`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPHeader.html#method-i-set_range) convenience method that takes as arguments either a single Range object (e.g. `60...80`) or a start index and length:

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"

url = URI.parse("http://example.com/foo")
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)

req.set_range(60, 20)

res = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port).start do |http|
  http.request(req)
end
puts res.body
```